# Web-scraping with the same tag html

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape from box office the left area in picture. Every value has the same tag html in the right areaHhow can i extract the different values from these tags?

All tags are the same as this

Running Time
1 hr 56 min

[image]

link of page:
https://www.boxofficemojo.com/title/tt1205489/?ref_=bo_cso_table_200

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put the code you have so far as text - (including the URL)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the container of those divs using the class `mojo-summary-values` which is unique, then you can loop through all the elements in the container and get the desired values.

The code I have given below fetches all the data given in the table and stores it in a dictionary.

To run my example you will need to install the following packages (pip):
`bs4` , `requests`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


URL = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/title/tt1205489/'

def get_box_office_mojo_data(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    data = {}
    for i,v in enumerate(soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'mojo-summary-values'})):
        cell_right = v.find_all('span')[1]
        
        if i==0: # Domestic Distributor
            domestic_distributor = cell_right.find(string=True, recursive=False)
            data.update({'domestic_distributor': domestic_distributor})

        elif i==1: # Domestic Opening
            domestic_opening = cell_right.find('span', attrs={'class': 'money'}).text
            data.update({'domestic_opening': domestic_opening})

        elif i==2: # Budget
            budget = cell_right.find('span', attrs={'class': 'money'}).text
            data.update({'budget': budget})

        elif i==3: # Release Date
            release_date = cell_right.text.split('\n')[0]
            data.update({'release_date': release_date})

        elif i==4: #MPAA
            mpaa = cell_right.text
            data.update({'mpaa': mpaa})

        elif i==5: # Running Time
            running_time = cell_right.text
            data.update({'running_time': running_time})

        elif i==6: # Genres
            genres = cell_right.text
            data.update({'genres': genres})

        elif i==7: # IMDb Pro Link
            imdb_pro_link = cell_right.find('a').attrs['href']
            data.update({'imdb_pro_link': imdb_pro_link})

    return data

from pprint import pprint
pprint(get_box_office_mojo_data(URL))
```

This Outputs:

```
{'budget': '$33,000,000',
 'domestic_distributor': 'Warner Bros.',
 'domestic_opening': '$271,720',
 'genres': 'Drama',
 'imdb_pro_link': 'https://pro.imdb.com/title/tt1205489?ref_=mojo_tt_summary&rf=mojo_tt_summary',
 'mpaa': 'R',
 'release_date': 'December 12, 2008',
 'running_time': '1 hr 56 min'}
```

EDIT: I just realized that using indices is not a consistent way to fetch the data, instead of checking for ex. `i==3`, you should probably first get the text from left cell and check if it is Release date or not.
like this `v.find_all('span')[0].text == 'Earliest Release Date'`

Comment: thanks u..its awesome but i dont yet understand all this code but very good and thanks